# Jquery Preload content In Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox-2, preload

I also wanted to use the jquery load.() function to preload the forms and load them when the fancybox is trigger.  I know the script to preload the forms but how to I make it only show when the fancybox is triggered?

Fancybox script

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
afterLoad: function () {
    if (this.type == "inline") {
        this.width = this.element.data("width");
        this.height = this.element.data("height");}}
'content' : $( "#new-projects" )    });
```

Preload Content

```
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/load.html #projects li" );
```

Answer (score 0):

load the content in hidden div,

```
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/load.html #projects li" );
```

then use [content](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) option of fancybox, as:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    ....
    'content' : $( "#new-projects" )
});
```

**Edit::**
you have extra parenthesis, do,

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function () {
        if (this.type == "inline") {
            this.width = this.element.data("width");
            this.height = this.element.data("height");
        }
    'content' : $( "#new-projects" )    
});
```

Comment: I have multiple forms to load the same way.  How do I do it for multiple contents? thx.

Comment: @Jen either you'll have to make your IDs unique or use class instead of ID for DIV container where you'll be loading the content, and use proper selector to pass in for 'content' in fancybox option

Comment: I get syntax error message in my code.  I updated it in my question.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Jen you have extra parenthesis closing for if condition close, see updated answer

Comment: The syntax error is because: 'content' : $( "#new-projects" )  is invalid js, the key 'content' :